# How can i compile openssl 1.1.1 for my UWP project?

Tags: uwp, tls1.3

I would like to use TLS1.3 in a UWP project, but i do not know how to compile this https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz for my UWP project.

Comment: Do you use uwp app as server?

Comment: No, i have a centos7 server which already support tls1.3, but the UWP client does not support.

Comment: It says "Windows and macOS do not yet support TLS 1.3. .NET Core 3.0 will support TLS 1.3 on these operating systems when support becomes available." at [Important](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0)

Comment: Sorry guys, you are right, currently UWP support max tls version is 1.2.

Comment: Is there a other way that i can use tls1.3 in my UWP app?

Comment: If the official document has not declare this, you could research some third part library to approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "perl configure VC-WIN32-ONECORE no-shared enable-capieng" to configure OpenSSL in "Visual Studio 2019 Tools Command Prompt".

And then run "nmake" and "nmake install". Now you can use OpenSSL in a "Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)" project.

But you have to add "libssl.lib;libcrypto.lib;Kernel32.lib" as "Additional Dependencies".

Or use "perl Configure VC-WIN32-ONECORE --release no-asm no-hw no-dso no-tests no-stdio no-async no-shared". then no need "Kernel32.lib".

Answer (score 0):

> would like to use TLS1.3 in a UWP project

I'm afraid you can't use TLS 1.3 in UWP platform. Derive from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.socketprotectionlevel?view=winrt-19041) the max version of supported TLS within UWP platform is 1.2. If you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub app, or pay attention to the following UWP SDK update.